# Pandas, does shift(1) give the next cell of a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, i'm trying to calculate daily returns & trying to understand pandas shift function.

```
frame = pd.read_csv('Correlation.csv')

Daily_Returns = frame['PG']/frame['PG'].shift(1)-1

Daily_Returns = (Selling_Price/Buying_Price)-1
```

Observations:

```
2/1/2000    30.855925
2/2/2000    30.584587
2/3/2000    30.332621
2/4/2000    29.382908
2/7/2000    28.917734
2/8/2000    29.692999
2/9/2000    29.150326
```

My question is, .shift(1) gives the next cell or the previous of any particular cell where shift is applied? Let's say I'm in 2/2/2000 when I call .shift(1), will it return 2/1/2000 or 2/3/2000?

Comment: Did you try reading the `shift` documentation?

Comment: Yes, in documentation it says parameter in shift can be positive integer or negative integer. However, when I pass 1, the above mentioned formula gives expected result. But when I shift the dataframe by -1 and print, second value become the first & so on.

I'm confused about the behavior, that's why looking for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

While the treatment of negative integers is not explicitly called out in the [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) documentation, negative indices typically mean an offset from the end of an iterable. This is a general concept in programming:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'][-1] == 'c' == ['a', 'b', 'c'][2]  # True
```

So in this case negative integers will shift the data in a Series/DataFrame up and positive integers will shift the data in a Series/DataFrame down.

```
s = pd.Series(list('abc'))
s.shift(1)
```

returns

```
0    NaN
1      a
2      b
dtype: object
```

and

```
s.shift(-1)
```

returns

```
0      b
1      c
2    NaN
dtype: object
```